# ¿Por qué obtengo 0. como resultado en esta red neuronal con Python?

Tags: python, variables, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy intentando hacer una red neuronal bastante simple la cual diferencie entre perros y gatos, pero a la hora de pasarle cualquier imagen el valor que siempre me devuelve es [0.]. Este es el código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jul 11 17:22:20 2022

@author: mariomiranda
"""

#Parte 1 de redes neuronales convolucionales

#Importamos las librerías y paquetes

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()

#Convolución

classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32,kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3),
                             activation = "relu"))
print(classifier)

#Paso 2: Max pulling. Aprende rotaciones y escalado de imágenes

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

print(classifier)

# Una segunda capa de convolucón y max pooling
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32,kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3),
                             activation = "relu"))
print(classifier.add)

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

print(classifier)

# Añadimos una tercera capa de convolución

classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32,kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3),
                             activation = "relu"))
print(classifier)

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

print(classifier.add)

# Añadimos una cuarta capa de convolución
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32,kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3),
                             activation = "relu"))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))


#Paso 3: Flattening o aplanado de lso datos. Construimos un vector para reducir el tamaño
# tiene que ser un vector unidimensional ya que así es la primera capa de la red neuronal

classifier.add(Flatten())

print(classifier)

#Paso 4: Full Conexion
#128 nodos en la capa oculta

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = "relu"))

print(classifier)
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")) # Función de activación

print(classifier)
#Compilar la red neuronal de convolución

classifier.compile(optimizer="adam", loss = "binary_crossentropy", 
                   metrics = ["accuracy"])
print(classifier)

#Parte 5: Importamos las imágenes para entrenar

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
print(train_datagen)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
print(test_datagen)

training_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/mariomiranda/Desktop/IA Python/dataset/training_set',
                                                    target_size=(64, 64),
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    class_mode='binary')
print(training_dataset)

testing_dataset = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/mariomiranda/Desktop/IA Python/dataset/test_set',
                                                target_size=(64, 64),
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode='binary')
print(testing_dataset)

classifier.fit_generator(training_dataset,
                        steps_per_epoch=len(training_dataset),
                        epochs=50,
                        validation_data=testing_dataset,
                        validation_steps=len(testing_dataset))

print(classifier.fit_generator)


# Importamos librerías necesarias

from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
import numpy as np

# Pasamos una imagen por la red neuronal

img_path = "/Users/mariomiranda/Desktop/Foto Sena/perro1.jpg"

print(img_path)

img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(64, 64))

# Para que la imagen sea procesada correctamnete, cambiamos el formato de la
# imagen. La ponemos en formato de batches porque es lo que espera la CNN

img_array = image.img_to_array(img)

img_batch = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

# Escalamos los pixeles de la imagen entre 0 y 1

img_preprocessed = preprocess_input(img_batch)

print(img_preprocessed)

# Prediccion

prediction = classifier.predict(img_preprocessed)

print(prediction)

if prediction > 0.5:

    solution = 'perro'

else:

    solution = 'gato'

print("La foto es de un",solution)
```

Lo que he hecho con la imagen ha sido procesarla para que sea posible pasarla por la red neuronal y tenga el tamaño correcto así como todas sus catacterísticas. No se si habré cometido algún error a la hora de crear la red neuronal pero he tenido que añadir alguna capa más de convolución para que la red pudiera llegar al 85% de precisión en test.A ver si alguno de vosotros puede echarme un cable, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Dónde devuelve el valor? ¿En qué parte del código se detecta el problema?

Comment: Ya lo tengo solucionado, conseguí finalmente cambiar una parte del código y ya no me devuelve 0 como valor